# Unable to access a simple web application (running on Tomcat Server) from another System

Tags: tomcat6

I have written a simple web Application which is running(on Tomcat Server) fine on my local system.But when I tried to access from a different system using http:/my_ip_address:8080/Projec1/My_Application. Its showing this error

**Network Error (tcp_error) 
A communication error occurred: ""
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.**

I know many of you must be well versed with this kinda error.But for me its kinda new.I would be happy if you state possible reason and solutions(Please tell me if there is configuration is required in Server step wise)

Thanks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot tell you all that i found the answer of above question, actually there was proxy setting problem.This is what i did

1. Open internet option in IE.
2. Goto LAN setting in Connection option.
3. In LAN Setting there is advance setting tab, click it.
4. You will see a Exception box at the bottom.
5. Type the IP Address form which you want access.
   eg. 10.200;*.xyz.com
6. This setting is to be done on system from where you want to access your web application.
7. Starting IP address where application is running 10.200.---.--- that is why in exception box it is mentioned as 10.200;*.(your Interanet Server Name)

Hope this will help.

Thanks

Comment: Though I'm able to view the web application from other system. But its not working properly. What I mean whenever its required to access database from the web page its not hitting the DB and getting the values on the web page.Please help!! till then I'm looking for it....

Comment: Yes it got resolved later, it was ajax URL problem. Please check the ajax URL make it ../project_name/file_name not full path as http://localhost:8080/project_name/file_name.